# How to ask someone to complete a sentence, like on a test or exercise?

Tags: sentence-construction, writing

> “I know that I’m good at singing.”
>
> “I know that ________.”

I want to make someone form the first sentence by adding a clause to the second one.

In this situation, can I say, “Write that you’re good at singing in a subordinate clause of verb ‘know’”?

Comment: Finish the sentence by adding what you are good at.

Comment: There's no indirect speech in your example.

Comment: Who are you talking to here? Why do you want them to complete this sentence in that particular way? For example, are you teaching someone how to create sentences with "I know that..."?

Comment: @gotube♦ Yes, but not actual person.